# Pytorch loss function error in the last batch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

Assume that I have 77 samples to train my CNN, and my `batch size` is 10. Then the last batch has a `batch size` of 7 instead of 10. Somehow when I pass it to the loss function such as `nn.MSELoss()`, it gives me the error:

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor
>   b (7) at non-singleton dimension 1

So pytorch doesn't support batches with different sizes?

### My code in doubt:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
import torchvision
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, (5,4))
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, x.shape[1] * x.shape[2] * x.shape[3])
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

model = Net()

batch_size = 10

# Generating Artifical data
x_train = torch.randn((77,1,20,20))
y_train = torch.randint(0,10,size=(77,),dtype=torch.float)

trainset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train,y_train)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
# testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(20):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i%10==0:
            print('epoch{}, step{}, loss: {}'.format(epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss))
#             print("frac post = {}".format(frac_post))
            running_loss = 0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not due to the batch size, but to a failure to broadcast properly between the 10 outputs of your CNN and the single label provided in each example.
If you look at the model output and label tensor shapes during the batch where the error is thrown,

```py
print(outputs.shape, labels.shape)
#out: torch.Size([7, 10]) torch.Size([7])
```

you'll see that the labels are stored in a singleton tensor. According to [pytorch broadcasting rules](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html), to be broadcastable two tensors have to be compatible in all trailing dimensions. In this case, the trailing dimension of the model output (10) is incompatible with that of the label (7).

To fix, either add a dummy dimension to the label (assuming you actually want to broadcast the labels to match your ten network outputs), or define a network with scalar outputs. For example:

```py
y_train = torch.randint(0,10,size=(77,1),dtype=torch.float)
```

results in

```
print(outputs.shape, labels.shape)
#out: torch.Size([7, 10]) torch.Size([7,1])
# these are broadcastable
```

Comment: Since my `batch_size` is coincidentally same as the `output size` 10, I was assuming `batch_size` is the culprit for the error. Now everything is crystal clear.